# How to use regex in .net to detect sql select statements in ruby source code

Tags: c#, regex

I've got an odd requirement to parse Ruby files looking for SQL SELECT statements in C#. I figured regex would be better solution than manually parsing the file, but now I have two problems ;). The difficulty arises in the many ways to declare a string, therefore a SQL statement in Ruby.

https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Strings_-_Creation_and_Basics

I've made good progress however I'm a bit stuck on one case.

For instance the regex

```regex
(?:<<~)?"?(\w*|%{|")?"?\s*(SELECT[\s\S]*)(?=}|"|\1)
```

Is looking to capture the SQL statement in the third capture group i.e.

```sql
SELECT user, name
FROM users
WHERE users.id = 2
```

The above regex captures the SQL statement in

```ruby
<<~"sqlHeredocDelimiter" 
    SELECT user, name
    FROM users
    WHERE users.id = 2
sqlHeredocDelimiter
# some other text selecting nothing
```

and

```ruby
sqlVariable = %{
    SELECT user, name
    FROM users
    WHERE users.id = 2
}
# some other text selecting nothing
```

however

```ruby
sqlVariable = "SELECT user, name FROM user where users.id = 2"
# some other text selecting nothing
```

Will keep capturing up until the end of the comment on the following line, rather than just capturing the required SQL statement.

Any help on this would be most appreciated as I'm feeling a little stuck at the moment.

Comment: Do you need the actual complete SELECT Statement itself or just Filename/LineNumber?

Comment: Note that Ruby string literals may also be defined within single quotation marks. You need a conditional or simple alternations to only match what you need.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yeah I know, there's a few more permutations I need to support, but I'm stuck on trivial strings at the moment

Comment: @Fildor I need to extract the SQL statement, I know the filename, line number would be a nice feature however

Comment: They are not trivial strings, they are string literals that are part of code, and the code may contain comments where one may put anything one wants, and that may make your regex match unexpected strings. You can't use a single regex for such a task, you need a parser.

Comment: often a good regex environment can help a lot. If you aren't using one I strongly recommend to do so. ( I like to use [regex101](https://regex101.com/) )

Comment: Like this? https://regex101.com/r/ON8KzR/1

Comment: @wp78de close, but can't rely on any particular variable name or heredoc delimiter, I've updated the question to reflect this

Comment: I see. How about this: https://regex101.com/r/ON8KzR/2

Comment: @wp78de well done, you have succeeded brilliantly in the face of adversity, you deserve a medal, thank you very much